# Android. Hide SupportActionBarin the top

Tags: android

I have hided SupportActionBar like this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
```

before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

my activity theme `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

but i have this line in the top

[image]

requirement!

my listener in navigationView menu items dont work if i do like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

so i need hide toolbar only programmaticaly

UPD

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivityimplements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

/////code


}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/view_nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_main_container

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.timecontrolapp.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlt_middle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/lnr_timer"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_bar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="12 November 18"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fontLarge"
                    tools:ignore="SpUsage" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rlt_search_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_search"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp40"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/edit_search"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:maxLength="25"
                        android:paddingStart="35dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="35dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rlt_voice"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="23dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp10"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp10"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp10"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp10"
                            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_white"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:src="@drawable/icon_voice"
                            android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rlt_cancel"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="22dp"
                            android:layout_height="23dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp10"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp10"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp10"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp10"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp10"
                            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_white"
                            android:padding="3dp"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:src="@drawable/icon_cancel"
                            android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lnr_timer"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_bar_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="00:00"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fontExtra"
                    tools:ignore="SpUsage" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/time_elapsed"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fontSmall"
                    tools:ignore="SpUsage" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_main_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_main_content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/view_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.timecontrolapp.activities.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main_container">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What actually you want? Please clear your requirements

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman thanks for a comment. I need to remove toolbar line(in screenshot) but withoit xml theme, i mean something like this: `getSupportActionBar()).hide()` in Activity

Comment: Add your Activity and layout xml

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman i have updated

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman thanks, but it doesnt help. I still have problem like in the screenshot